# I Want to Know Why Magic Function Is Giving Specific Answer For Specific Operator

Tags: python, operator-overloading, magic-function

I was Using Magic Functions(Operator Overloading) In Python When I Came To Know that for a Specific Operator Python Is giving a Specific Answer

```
class over:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x=x
    def __add__(self,other):
        return over(self.x+other.x)
ob1=over(20)
ob2=over(30)
ob3=over(40)
ob4=ob1+ob2+ob3              #It Is adding All three
print(ob4.x)           # This Gave Me answer As 90
```

But When I Used Another Magic Function Such As Greater Then (**gt**) the It was Just Addinglast two Values namely ob2 and ob3

```
class over:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x=x
    def __gt__(self,other):
        return over(self.x+other.x)
ob1=over(20)
ob2=over(30)
ob3=over(40)
ob4=ob1>ob2>ob3     # This Is Just Adding Ob2 and Ob3
print(ob4.x)          #Result:70
```

I want to Get Result 90 As I got it in my First Code, By using **gt**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chaining for comparator operators happen bit different than `+`

```
a < b < c
```

is equivalent to

```
a < b and b < c
```

So your expression is actually being evaluated as:

```
(ob1 < ob2) and (ob2 < ob3)
```

Which gives

```
over(x=70)
```

Due to how the `and` operator works.

To make the expression work you need to add some parentheses:

```
(ob1 > ob2) > ob3
```

Which gives:

```
over(x=90)
```

Ref: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/chaining-comparison-operators-python/